# Why is accessing a variable so much slower than accessing len()?

Tags: performance, go, slice

I wrote this function `uniq` that takes in a sorted slice of `int`s
and returns the slice with duplicates removed:

```golang
func uniq(x []int) []int {
    i := 0
    for i < len(x)-1 {
        if x[i] == x[i+1] {
            copy(x[i:], x[i+1:])
            x = x[:len(x)-1]
        } else {
            i++
        }
    }
    return x
}
```

and `uniq2`, a rewrite of `uniq` with the same results:

```golang
func uniq2(x []int) []int {
    i := 0
    l := len(x)
    for i < l-1 {
        if x[i] == x[i+1] {
            copy(x[i:], x[i+1:])
            l--
        } else {
            i++
        }
    }
    return x[:l]
}
```

The only difference between the two functions
is that in `uniq2`, instead of slicing `x`
and directly accessing `len(x)` each time,
I save `len(x)` to a variable `l`
and decrement it whenever I shift the slice.

I thought that `uniq2` would be slightly faster than `uniq`
because `len(x)` would no longer be called iteration,
but in reality, it is inexplicably *much* slower.

With this test that generates a random sorted slice
and calls `uniq`/`uniq2` on it 1000 times,
which I run on Linux:

```
func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        _ = uniq(genSlice())
        //_ = uniq2(genSlice())
    }
}
func genSlice() []int {
    x := make([]int, 0, 1000)
    for num := 1; num <= 10; num++ {
        amount := rand.Intn(1000)
        for i := 0; i < amount; i++ {
            x = append(x, num)
        }
    }
    return x
}
```

```bash
$ go build uniq.go
$ time ./uniq
```

`uniq` usually takes 5--6 seconds to finish.
while `uniq2` is more than two times slower,
taking between 12--15 seconds.

Why is `uniq2`, where I save the slice length to a variable,
so much slower than `uniq`, where I directly call `len`?

Shouldn't it slightly faster?

Comment: you forgot to add `x = x[:l]` on `uniq2` after `l--`

Comment: @RahmatFathoni I don't need to slice `x` in `uniq2` there because I never call `len(x)` again, and I keep track of `l` so I can slice `x` once at the end.  I've tested both functions and confirmed that they both work and their output is the same; the only difference is their speed.

Comment: If you add it, the benchmark is almost same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You expect roughly the same execution time because you think they do roughly the same thing.

> The only difference between the two functions is that in `uniq2`, instead of slicing `x` and directly accessing `len(x)` each time, I save `len(x)` to a variable `l` and decrement it whenever I shift the slice.

This is wrong.

The first version does:

```
        copy(x[i:], x[i+1:])
        x = x[:len(x)-1]
```

And second does:

```
        copy(x[i:], x[i+1:])
        l--
```

The first difference is that the first assigns (copies) a slice header which is a [`reflect.SliceHeader`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#SliceHeader) value, being 3 integer (24 bytes on 64-bit architecture), while `l--` does a simple decrement, it's much faster.

But the main difference does not stem from this. The main difference is that since the first version changes the `x` slice (the header, the length included), you end up copying less and less elements, while the second version does not change `x` and always copies to the end of the slice. `x[i+1:]` is equivalent to `x[x+1:len(x)]`.

To demonstrate, imagine you pass a slice with length=10 and having all equal elements. The first version will copy 9 elements first, then 8, then 7 etc. The second version will copy 9 elements first, then 9 again, then 9 again etc.

Let's modify your functions to count the number of copied elements:

```
func uniq(x []int) []int {
    count := 0
    i := 0
    for i < len(x)-1 {
        if x[i] == x[i+1] {
            count += copy(x[i:], x[i+1:])
            x = x[:len(x)-1]
        } else {
            i++
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("uniq copied", count, "elements")
    return x
}

func uniq2(x []int) []int {
    count := 0
    i := 0
    l := len(x)
    for i < l-1 {
        if x[i] == x[i+1] {
            count += copy(x[i:], x[i+1:])
            l--
        } else {
            i++
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("uniq2 copied", count, "elements")
    return x[:l]
}
```

Testing it:

```
uniq(make([]int, 1000))
uniq2(make([]int, 1000))
```

Output is:

```
uniq copied 499500 elements
uniq2 copied 998001 elements
```

**`uniq2()` copies twice as many elements!**

If we test it with a random slice:

```
uniq(genSlice())
uniq2(genSlice())
```

Output is:

```
uniq copied 7956671 elements
uniq2 copied 11900262 elements
```

**Again, `uniq2()` copies roughly 1.5 times more elements!** (But this greatly depends on the random numbers.)

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/QCmuuPMDtfR).

The "fix" is to modify `uniq2()` to copy until `l`:

```
        copy(x[i:], x[i+1:l])
        l--
```

With this "appropriate" change, performance is roughly the same.